# ExtJS - Changing default button styles and fonts

Tags: extjs4.1

I have this requirement where I have to change the default styles on my Ext JS application. I am not talking about changing stuff in CSS files yet. I am not that ambitious yet. Here is what I am looking for:

1. Suppose I need a Submit and Cancel buttons, I use xtype:button and text:Save ( or Cancel ). This will render buttons with the text on them. What should I do if I want to change the look and feel of the button? Or replace the button with a cool Save or Cancel image?
2. Right now I have all the texts on the application with the default font that ExtJS shows. What am I supposed to do if I want all the text on the application changed to a different font? Everything right from the data in forms/grids and the titles of each component should be changed to some other font my customer prefers. What am I supposed to do?

I understand these are very basic and a generic questions, but I am looking for a good headsup before I proceed with my task.

Thank you all in advance. Waiting for answers :)

Update: So, I found out how we deal with CSS and change the fonts. Can anyone help about the Chaning the look and feel for Submit/Cancel buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [compass](http://compass-style.org/) to build your own themes, or better said to change one the existing themes. In the [Ext JS documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-css_var-S-button-arrow-height) you can find the css variables which you can set according to your needs.

Comment: The second question, i got the answer. I can just add a new CSS file with my preferences add to my application and then add them into my view files. I don't want to risk play around with the API provided CSS files. Is it the same way I change the button look and feel? Basically, the API documentation show Add/Delete etc various buttons in the grid/form examples which look nice. How can I use them? Where do I find them? How to ise them in my components?

Comment: Yes it is the same way - fonts and 'look and feel' are declared in css classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not ready for theming with SASS just yet take a look at this example of button configs from the sencha docs:

Stanadalone **Example** page: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/button/button.html

**CSS** that adds customized images to the buttons: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/button/button.css

**JS** that shows button configs:  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/button/button.js

Essentially this shows how to use `iconCls` property on the button config along with a simple CSS class to add desired image to your button.