# ext.js 5.0.0 image button

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

Is it possible to override button background image **in all states: normal, hover, pressed** in ext.js 5.0.0? I tried to use the following css code without success:

```
.fieldNameCls
{

}

.fieldDataCls
{

}

.x-btn.removeButtonCls {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
//  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: url('images/RemoveDetailButton.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.x-btn-over.removeButtonCls {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: url('images/RemoveDetailButtonHover.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.x-btn-pressed.removeButtonCls {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: url('images/RemoveDetailButtonPressed.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

The js button is defined as follows:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'removeButton',
    cls: 'removeButtonCls',
    // style: 'background:url("resources/images/RemoveDetailButton.png") no-repeat; background-size: 100% !important; border-style: none !important;border-radius: 0px !important;',
    // style: 'background:none !important; border-style: none !important;border-radius: 0px !important;',
    margin: '10 10 0 0'
}
```

I tried to understand which classes to override, but failed to understand with all the div/span Ext.js uses per button... ;)

Should I just use some HTML button instead, it would be much easier to override, but as a newbie to Web design, I am not sure how I will be able to get events from that button / change text ...

Thanks

Comment: Try this will help you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608270/extjs-changing-default-button-styles-and-fonts`

Comment: They provide examples on how to add image to a button. But Ext.js button has multiple styles / layers I just don't need. All I want is a decent image button with 3 states: normal, hover, pressed. I want it square, no styles, and single image per state. Should I just use HTML button as a custom component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, I know it wont be exactly "meta-correct" with the infinite uniformness of stackoverflow, but I want to share also how to get custom button with text, in case anybody need. It has totally another approach, and is using standard ext.js button classes:

in js:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Add Detail',
    baseCls: 'contactDetailsEditButtonCls'
},
```

in scss:

.ContactDetailsEditTitle
    {
      background-color: transparent !important;
      color: #46a6f2;
      vertical-align: middle;
      height: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

```
.ContactDetailsEditImage
{
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -o-border-radius: 0px;
  -ms-border-radius: 0px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: #d5d5d5;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.ContatDetailsEditImageOverlayLabel
{
  width: 128px;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.30) !important;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.contactDetailsButtonCls
{
//  left: 0px !important;
//  top: 0px !important;
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  //line-height: 40px !important;
  background-color: #ff8409 !important;
  background-size: 100% !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.x-btn-over.contactDetailsButtonCls
{
//  left: 0px !important;
//  top: 0px !important;
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  //line-height: 40px !important;
  background-color: #ffaf0d !important;
  background-size: 100% !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.x-btn-pressed.contactDetailsButtonCls
{
//  left: 0px !important;
//  top: 0px !important;
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  //line-height: 40px !important;
  background-color: #f3330d !important;
  background-size: 100% !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once you know how, it's easy :)

in Ext.js:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'removeButton',
    baseCls: 'removeButtonCls',
    margin: '10 10 0 0'
}
```

in CSS:

```
.removeButtonCls {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  //  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: url('images/RemoveDetailButton.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.removeButtonCls :hover {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  //  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: url('images/RemoveDetailButtonHover.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.removeButtonCls :active {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  //  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: url('images/RemoveDetailButtonPressed.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

That easy ..

Answer (score 0):

This is my example. Sorry my English.

```
            {
                xtype: 'button', // #26
                cls:'blue',
                itemId: 'submit',
                formBind: true,  // #27
                iconCls: 'key-go',
                text: "Submit"
            }
```

In CSS.

```
.blue
{
    -- border: 2px solid #9A9C9C; /*or this*/
    border-color: #9A9C9C;
    border-width: 2px;

    border-radius: 20px;
}

.blue .x-btn-inner /*spacer is space.  This for text and background inner text*/
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #BCBEBE !important;    
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.x-btn-over.blue /*is concatenating. This for border and background in over event*/
{
    border-color: #008080;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #008080 !important;    
}

.x-btn-over.blue .x-btn-inner /*spacer is space. This for text in over event*/
{
    background-color: #68ACAC !important;       
    color: #FFFF00;
}
```

If need, replace "-over" on "-focus","-pressed" or "-disabled".

And this example for All buttons in project.

```
.x-btn  {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: #008080;
    padding:5px !important;
    border-width: 3px;
}


.x-btn  .x-btn-inner{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7786A2;
}
.x-btn-over {
    border-color: red;
    --border-width: 3px;
}

.x-btn-over .x-btn-inner{ /*spacer is space.  This for text in over event*/
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: 1. where is the image? 2. for any of you considering extjs: In my opinion? RUN FOR YOUR LIFE! ... the most complex, slow to manage (slow as in dead snail..), very very hard to customize... JUST USE ANYTHING ELSE.. ANYTHING